# How can I release ownership of a resource managed by a Cleaner?

Tags: kotlin, java-native-interface, move-semantics, ownership-semantics

Suppose I have a wrapper object like this:

```kotlin
private val CLEANER = java.lang.ref.Cleaner.create()

internal typealias Ptr = Long
private external fun acquireResource(): Ptr
private external fun disposeResource(nativePtr: Ptr)

/* ... */

class Resource private constructor (private val nativePtr: Ptr):
    Closeable, AutoCloseable
{
    companion object {
        fun create(): Resource {
            return Resource(acquireResource())
        }
    }

    private val cleanable = CLEANER.register(this, object: Runnable {
        private val nativePtr = this@Resource.nativePtr

        override fun run() {
            disposeResource(nativePtr)
        }
    })

    override fun close() {
        cleanable.clean()
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Now suppose I want to write a method `internal fun release(): Ptr` that makes the `Resource` give up ownership on `nativePtr` and then return it: in other words, when the `Resource` on which I called `release` is garbage-collected, its `nativePtr` pointer should not be disposed. (I intend that the `Resource` object should not be used after `release` is called, though I don’t see any way to enforce this.) This would allow me to pass the `Ptr` to an API that will manage its lifetime from then on.

How can I write `release`, preferably in an atomic/thread-safe manner? Is it even compatible with `Cleaner`?

(In other words, I am looking for an API equivalent to JavaScript’s [`FinalizationRegistry.prototype.unregister`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry/unregister).)

Comment: OpenJDK’s implementation of `Cleaner` hands out `Cleanable`s that simply are `PhantomReference`s, on which one can simply invoke `clear` to disown them: <https://code.yawk.at/java/12/java.base/jdk/internal/ref/PhantomCleanable.java#jdk.internal.ref.PhantomCleanable%23clear()>. And it’s even used internally: <https://code.yawk.at/java/12/java.base/java/io/FileDescriptor.java#java.io.FileDescriptor%23unregisterCleanup()>. But it doesn’t seem to be anywhere in the public API.

Comment: I find it a little hard to follow what is asked here. Am I right to say that conditionally you don't want the cleanable.run() to actually invoke the disposeResource() function? Because if so... then that simply needs to be made actually conditional, a simply boolean flag would do it.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, pretty much. I want to do the sort of thing that in C++ is accomplished by [`std::unique_ptr<T>::release`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release). What’s the JVM equivalent?